# How to change your password on iPad?

Tags: ios, ipad, password

How do I change my password on my iPad?

Comment: Extremely poor research....this was easily googleable. Please explain why this was upvoted?

Comment: I am pretty new to this community, but I am a regular SO user. This would count as wasting everybody's time there.

Answer (score 1):

Settings → (Touch ID &) Passcode, enter your passcode, then choose Change Passcode.

Answer (score 1):

Go to Settings > Touch ID & Passcode. On devices without Touch ID, go to Settings > Passcode.

Article: https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204060#adjust